# How to obtain some telegram accounts to test my project

Tags: testing, telegram, account

I need three telegram accounts to test my project. Is it possible to create or obtain them someway? Or i have to buy three sim-cards and register three accounts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented in here:
https://core.telegram.org/api/auth#test-accounts

Basically you need to connect to test DC with specific number in range `99966XYYYY`, confirmation code is always `XXXXX` (X from phone number repeated 5 times where X must be between 1-3).

If you want to login to test account on telegram desktop:

- Hold `Alt+Shift` and right click on “Add account”, then choose “Test server”
- Country code is + and type `9996621111`, then confirm with code `22222`

For Android:

- Country code is +999 and type `6621111`, then confirm with code `22222`

Comment: The alt+shift is not needed anymore. Now simply go to "add account" then choose to login with phone number. Once there's the field to specify the number, you can remove country code and write the test number like explained in this answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, right now you need to buy 3 mobile numbers to have 3 accounts. But I would suggest you to get private mobile numbers from the service provider, you can use trial account too, because once you signed in, all the future OTPs you can get in the telegram itself. ;-)

Comment: what does OTP stand for?

Comment: @FoNko One Time Password - usually received in SMS or Call or Email