# Publishing an unofficial version of Telegram in Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, telegram, publishing

My app is an unofficial version of Telegram app that has been already published in Play Store. For first publishing and a few updates afterward, there was no problem for login from Google. But my last update was rejected as below:

> Issue: Need login credentials for app review
> In order for us to review your app for compliance with Developer Program Policies, we will need you to provide valid login credentials for your app.
> If users need credentials to access your app, please provide all appropriate credentials via Play Console.
> If you previously supplied credentials, please ensure that they have not expired.
> If your app normally uses 2-Step Verification (e.g. SMS verification), biometrics (e.g. a fingerprint or face scan) or a location-dependent password (e.g. geo-gate), please provide valid demo credentials that we can use instead.

My question is how to provide an account for Play Store to review my app? or is there any demo account for Telegram to check?
Thanks

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently faced a similar problem and here is my solution.

1. First of all, I found this [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/api/auth#test-accounts).
   Here you can find these test phone numbers/accounts which you can
   use.
2. In the BuildVars file, I've set both DEBUG_VERSION and
   DEBUG_PRIVATE_VERSION to "true".
3. Deploy an app and check how it works with Test Accounts. Don't
   forget: It's very necessary to tick the "Test Backend" checkbox,
   otherwise, Telegram Test Accounts will not work!
4. I turned on a "Managed publishing" in the Google Play Console (it
   allows you to send a Bundle to review and manually send an app to
   production after it if needed).
5. I described how exactly the Google Play Team should use these
   accounts to check my app in App Content -> App access in Google Play
   Console.
6. After I passed the review, I built another Bundle, in which I've set
   both DEBUG_VERSION and DEBUG_PRIVATE_VERSION back to "false" and
   sent this bundle to the review again (this version will go to
   Production)

Comment: Thanks, your answer really helped me and solved my problem

Comment: @david What's is the country code of the test number?

Comment: @SmartManoj I don't think the phone number has anything to do with the country code, it's just a test number

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75358556/5033247